# Why isn't sizeof() printing 16 bytes instead of 8?

Tags: c++, sizeof

Pretty simple program, I'm just testing the `sizeof()` function and trying to see if it works. If sizeof() really does return things in terms of bits, when I had these two elements, shouldn't it return 16 instead of 8? Since `long long` is 8 bytes in C++ and I have two elements?

```
int main()
{
    long long whatever[] = {0};
    std::cout << whatever[0] << std::endl;
    whatever[2] = 10;

    std::cout << "The size of this array is " << sizeof(whatever[0] + whatever[2]) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you have two elements?  You explicitly initialize it with 1 element.  The whatever[2] = 10 assignment is a bug, not a way to extend the array.

Comment: `sizeof(whatever[0] + whatever[2])` is not the same as `sizeof(whatever[0]) + sizeof(whatever[2])`.

Comment: @DrewHall guess I need to reread how arrays work. Why was the the whatever[2] assignment a bug and not me 'extending the array'?

Comment: You cannot extend arrays, their size is fixed.

Comment: `whatever` is an array with only 1 element in it, so the only valid element you can access is `whatever[0]`, `whatever[2]` is out of bounds.

Comment: I'd recommend turning on/up your compiler warnings. All three of GCC, Clang, and MSVC [warn for your invalid array access](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/G8Gxs8Ejf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is undefined behavior

```
long long whatever[] = {0};
std::cout << whatever[0] << std::endl;
whatever[2] = 10;  // BAD
```

The code statically initializes `whatever` as an array of one element. Then you assign a value to `whatever[2]`.  The only valid index in that array is `0`.  Assigning anything to index `1` or `2` overwrites the important stuff on the stack or does other nefarious things.

You probably meant:

```
long long whatever[2] = {0};
std::cout << whatever[0] << std::endl;
whatever[1] = 10; 

std::cout << "The size of this array is " << sizeof(whatever) << std::endl;
```

Comment: oh, makes sense. what if i changed it to `whatever[3]`

Comment: I updated my answer. to show you how to use `sizeof` on individual elements.

Comment: Is you initialize whatever to have a size of 3, that will fix the undefined behavior.

Comment: i reinitialized the array and changed the thing in the cout line and it worked. thanks bro. in python you can make arrays with declaring the size. but what if i didnt know how many things i would need to fit in a thing? im imagining if i was working at boeing or a financial services company and i dont know how much information ill be taking in. how could i resize the array?

Comment: In c++, use the `std::vector` instead of an array.

Comment: got ittttt. deleting this post. owe you one man

Comment: don't delete - upvote the answers that helped you.

Answer (score 10):

You are not measuring the size of an array, but the size of the sum of two `long long`s. I.e.,

```
sizeof(whatever[0] + whatever[2])
```

is essentially the same as

```
sizeof(long long)
```

which you point out is 8.

Answer (score 3):

You declared an array with one element. So the valid index for this array is 0. As a result using the value equal to 2 as an index value in this expression

```
whatever[2] = 10;
```

results in accessing memory beyond the array that invokes undefined behavior.

As for the operator `sizeof` then  it does not evaluate its operand. It only determines the type of its operand and returns the size of an object of this type.

So this expression

```
sizeof(whatever[0] + whatever[2])
```

where you may use an invalid index for the array `whatever` is equivalent to the expression

```
sizeof( long long )
```

From the C++ 14 Standard (5.3.3 Sizeof)

> 1 The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object
> representation of its operand. **The operand is either an expression,
> which is an unevaluated operand** (Clause 5), or a parenthesized
> type-id.